# How to update password through passwordstrength AJAX control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have developed a webpage ASP.net with C# which use to update password in oracle database using AJAX `PasswordStrenght` Control. When Password meets the depict requirements, by clicking on button it should update password in database. However when I click on button it is not update password in databse.

PasswordStrenght Code:-

```
<ajaxToolkit:PasswordStrength ID="PasswordStrength1" runat="server" DisplayPosition="RightSide" StrengthIndicatorType="BarIndicator"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" PrefixText="Stength:" Enabled="true"
    RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="true" MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="1"
    MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="1" MinimumSymbolCharacters="1"
    MinimumNumericCharacters="1" PreferredPasswordLength="10"
    TextStrengthDescriptions="VeryPoor; Weak; Average; Strong; Excellent"
    StrengthStyles="VeryPoor; Weak; Average; Excellent; Strong;"
    CalculationWeightings="25;25;15;35" BarBorderCssClass="border"
    HelpStatusLabelID="Label1" />
```

Please refer below code :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label2.Text = Session["PERNR"].ToString();
        Label3.Text = Session["ZZFNAME"].ToString();

    }

}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Label1.Text == "" && TextBox1.Text != "")
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.127.240.216/ipcldb;User ID=ipcltos;Password=ipcltos;Unicode=True");
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATE SAP_EMPMST SET PASSWORD = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE PERNR = '" + Label2.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string display = "New Password has been updated...!!!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
        con.Close();
    }

    else
    {
        string display = "New Password is not matching with security requirments...!!!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if I enter the password `'; drop table SAP_EMPMST --`? or `LetMeInOnAnyAccount';--` Ohh bad stuff :/ As for why it's not updating... umm there's not a lot to go on here, it looks technically correct. Does the query working outside the code? What values are you seeing when debugging?

Comment: @HugoYates yes query works if I remove `if...else` loop